# How to get the line number of an error in Igor Script?

Tags: igor

I have an ipf file that calls SetDataFolder and compiles fine.

> While executing SetDataFolder, the following error occurred: No child
>   data folder of that name exists.

Cool, except I call SetDataFolder everywhere. Is there anyway at all to get the line number?

Answer (score 0):

I would enable "Debugging" and "Debug on Error" both reachable from the Procedure menu. With that checked the debugger pops up on all errors.